How to use a GitHub organization as Poetry package source for multiple code repos
Is there a way to specify a GitHub organization as source in poetry so that we can use one token to install multiple private git repositories as dependencies?
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
lib1 = {git = "https://github.com/MyOrg/lib1", branch="main"}

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "privaterepo1"
priority = "primary"
url = "https://github.com/MyOrg/lib1"


This will work with poetry lock and poetry install when we set the token POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_PRIVATEREPO1_PASSWORD with a GitHub personal access token.
But when we want to install multiple git repositories as dependencies, the only option I could find is to define one source per repository.
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
lib1 = {git = "https://github.com/MyOrg/lib1", branch="main"}
lib2 = {git = "https://github.com/MyOrg/lib2", branch="main"}

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "privaterepo1"
priority = "primary"
url = "https://github.com/MyOrg/lib1"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "privaterepo2"
priority = "primary"
url = "https://github.com/MyOrg/lib2"

And then set two environment variables POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_PRIVATEREPO1_PASSWORD and POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_PRIVATEREPO2_PASSWORD.
Is there a way to specify one GitHub organization or a url prefix so that we can install multiple repos from the same org using one token? Something like below.
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
lib1 = {git = "https://github.com/MyOrg/lib1", branch="main"}
lib2 = {git = "https://github.com/MyOrg/lib2", branch="main"}

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "privaterepo"
priority = "primary"
url = "https://github.com/MyOrg"


And using only one token in env variable POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_PRIVATEREPO_PASSWORD

I think you can easily do it if you use SSH based authentication, SSH agent, instead of HTTP. No passwords or environment variables needed.
